# How to properly use the O_DIRECT flag with memory alignment in Linux C?

Tags: c, linux, memory, alignment, system-calls

When I use the system call open() with the flag O_DIRECT and call write() to write a file directly, I should make memory alignment, that means when I malloc a block of memory, the address of this memory should be an integer multiple of the file system block size(take 4KB as an example), and the size of the memory that I applied should also be the integer multiple of 4KB. The first question of mine is: is my understanding of the usage of the O_DIRECT flag correct? And then, how do I request a block of memory aligned to the block size? Thanks a lot!

I browsed some blogs and tried the methods in them, but it didn't work. And I am a primer programmer in Linux C. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[man open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)

> **O_DIRECT**
>
> ... File I/O is done directly to/from user-space buffers. ...

[man write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

> **ERRORS**
>
> **EINVAL**
>
> ... the file was opened with the O_DIRECT flag, and either the address specified in buf, the value specified in count, or the file offset is not suitably aligned.

C11 memory alignment:

- [_Alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas)
- [_Alignof operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof)
- [aligned_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc)

For memory alignment under linux:

- see GNU C Library reference [Allocating Aligned Memory Blocks](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html)